# While loop doesn't honor the constraint

Tags: python, while-loop

The below line of code runs however the while loop doesn't stop when len(fib_list) reaches < 20. It continues instead to add on to the list albeit backwards. Any ideas?

```py
fib_list = [0,1]

def fib(n, sum):
    while len(fib_list) < 20:
        for i in range(n, len(fib_list)):
            sum += fib_list[i]
            n += 1
            print(n, sum, len(fib_list))
            fib_list.append(sum)
            fib(n, sum)
        else:
            break
        
fib(0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a for loop in the while loop and a recursive call in the for loop. This is very bad practice in general and will cause you many headaches. It doesn't stop when len(fib_list) reaches 20 because as long as the while loop execute once, your for loop and the recursive calls will execute. In your recursive call, len(fib_list) could be < 20 and it will go into the while loop, starting the for loop once again.

Comment: Thanks. So a for loop in a while loop which calls a function is not good practice? I'm gonna have to figure this out

Comment: A for loop in a while loop is fine. The issue is that your loops, as well as the recursive call fib(n, sum) are all dependent on len(fib_list) which is constantly changing. What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe we could point you towards the right direction.

Comment: yeah its ringing a bell now. I remember how it is not a good idea to have your loop dependent on a variable that constantly changing. I'm doing something relatively simple which is to create a list of fibonnoci numbers. There's definitely easier ways to do it but I was just practicing with using loops. So in essence, for all loops, it's not recommended to have their constraints changing?

Comment: Yes, you should avoid modifying a list as you're iterating over it.